# Como pegar o evento quando um input recebe texto do autocomplete? Sem JqueryUI?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Preciso saber se tem como perceber(evento) quando estou navegando no listbox gerado pelo autocomplete do Chrome (por exemplo) quando automaticamente ele joga os valores de endereço, telefone, etc, nos campos do formulário que tiverem tais `id´s`. Ou seja, preciso estilizar cada campo exatamente quando o navegador joga textos do autocomplete nos campos.
Segue o código como está:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="nome">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="telefone">
<style>
body{
 background:#555555;
}
input {
 height:40px; font-size:12pt;
 background: transparent;
}
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000000 !important;
}</style>
</body>
</html>
```